# Enemy rotates after the player 2D OpenGL

Tags: c++, 2d, game-development

[image]

So, I got to do a project, where I have to use a given framework for OpenGL.

The project theme is "Survival Shooter 2D".
Now I am trying to implement an enemy that follow the player. The enemy is the black square with green eyes and the player is the blue square with the red eyes.
And from what I know I have to calculate the angle between the position of the enemy and the position of the player but I can't figure it out because everything is now in a viewport, a logic space.`//Body

```
modelMatrix = visMatrix;
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(translateX, translateY);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Scale(1, 1);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(playerAngle);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-50, -50);
    RenderMesh2D(meshes["square3"], shaders["VertexColor"], modelMatrix);

    //Eye1
    modelMatrix = visMatrix;
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(translateX, translateY);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Scale(0.25f, 0.25f);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(playerAngle);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(150, 200);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(0);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-50, -50);
    RenderMesh2D(meshes["square1"], shaders["VertexColor"], modelMatrix);

    //Eye2
    modelMatrix = visMatrix;
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(translateX, translateY);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Scale(0.25f, 0.25f);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(playerAngle);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-150, 200);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(0);
    modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-50, -50);
    RenderMesh2D(meshes["square1"], shaders["VertexColor"], modelMatrix);`
```

So this is how I draw my player.

```
//Body
modelMatrix = visMatrix;
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(300, 300);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Scale(1, 1);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(enemyAngle);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-50, -50);
RenderMesh2D(meshes["border"], shaders["VertexColor"], modelMatrix);

//Eye1
modelMatrix = visMatrix;
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(300, 300);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Scale(0.25f, 0.25f);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(enemyAngle);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(150, 200);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(0);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-50, -50);
RenderMesh2D(meshes["square2"], shaders["VertexColor"], modelMatrix);

//Eye2
modelMatrix = visMatrix;
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(300, 300);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Scale(0.25f, 0.25f);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(enemyAngle);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-150, 200);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Rotate(0);
modelMatrix *= transform2D::Translate(-50, -50);
RenderMesh2D(meshes["square2"], shaders["VertexColor"], modelMatrix);
```

And this is how I draw my enemy.

```
enemyAngle = -atan2(-(logicSpace.x + cursorPos.x - translateEnemyX) * 50, 50 * (logicSpace.y + window->GetResolution().y - cursorPos.y- translateEnemyY));
```

And I have tried to calculate the angle like this but it does not work.
And those constants are coming from the fact that the squares that I use for the body are 100x100, i dont know how to explain this better.

So the question is, how to calculate the angle for the enemy to make him rotate after the player while the player is moving?

Comment: _"i dont know how to explain this better."_ perhaps focus on what your question is?  I don't think there is currently any question here to answer.

Comment: I have updated my post with the question.

Comment: Try `enemyAngle = atan2(translateX - translateEnemyX, translateY - translateEnemyY)`

Comment: @Alex It's kinda working but its doing a full and correct rotation only if the player is quite far and is a bit off, its not pointing to the center of the player.